# Symfony autowire: Why is service injected as null?

Tags: symfony, autowired

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. While autowire seems to work fine for most services, some some dependencies are injeded as `null` which leads to exceptions...

`ServiceA` depends on `ServiceB`:

```
class ServiceA {
    private $serviceB;
    public function __construct(ServiceB $serviceB) {
        $this->serviceB = $serviceB;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        return $this->serviceB->someMethod();
    }
}

// Symfony 2.8 - src/AppBundle/Resources/services.yml
services:
    ...

    app.serviceB
        ...

    app.serviceA
        arguments:
            - "@app.serviceB"


// Symfony 3.4 - Using autowire in app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'  

    ...
```

In `Symfony 2.8` everything worked find and `$serviceA->doSomething()` was executed without any problem.

The same code with the `Symfony 3.4` config using `autowire` leads to an exception:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
>   Call to a member function **someMethod()** on **null**...

Thus it seems that `ServiceB` is not correctly injeced into `ServiceA`?

What could be the reason for this? There are no other exceptions within the logs, which would explain why `$serviceB` is null. It seems that `SercieB` can be created without any problem. Other services with other dependencies work just fine.

Comment: Where is `ServiceB` located?

Comment: What is `ServiceB`'s definition? Does it require anything?

Comment: Since you have type hinted constructor parameter  `__construct(ServiceB $serviceB)`, it's not possible to pass `null` to this constructor. If Symfony would try to do that, you would get a FatalError while trying to create `ServiceA` instance.
It would be better if you provide real code instead of this fake sample because I guess that you may have a mistake that may not even be present in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. After some more digging I found some warnings within the logs which where not related to mentioned services in any way. It seems that Symfony had trouble to initialize some totally different service. Although this problem had nothing to do with the reported error, solving the warning solved the error.

It seems that there is something wrong with the Symfony error reporting. I will investigate this further.

Since the problem described in the question is actually not the real problem here I first wanted to delete the question. However, the question and may answer might still help other who stumble about similar behavior...

Comment: For what it's worth, under Symfony 3 and above if you use DI to pass a service to a class and Symfony cannot figure out what it should be passing over it will say so with a very clear exception so getting errors like the one you got are a good indication that something else has gone wrong.